# C Programming stuck with calculating matrix (2D array)

Tags: c

Suppose that `A` is a `table` of floating point numbers, having `k` `rows` and `m` `columns`,
and `B` is a `table` of floating point numbers, having `m` `rows` and `n` `columns`. We wish to generate a `new table`, C, where each element of C is determined by:

```
C[i][j] = A[i][1]*B[1][j]+ A[i][2]*B[2][j]+ ,..., A[i][m]*B[m][j]

where i = 1, 2, …, k and j = 1, 2, …, n
```

and this is what I'm working on

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
float A[10][10], B[10][10], C[10][10];
int k, i, j, l, m, n;
printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix A:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&k,&m);
printf("Enter elements of matrix A:\n");
for (i=0;i<k;i++)
    for (j=0;j<m;j++)
    scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);

printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix B:\n");
scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
printf("Enter elements of matrix N:\n");
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
    scanf("%f",&B[i][j]);
```

After scanning two `matrix`, what should I do next to calculate `C`, this one is confusing me. I don't know if I'm able to put both `A` and `B` scanning into just one nested loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are using `m` twice. I think you meant `l` the first time.

Comment: oh that just a redundant one, I used m twice because the number of columns in A equal to the number of rows in B

Comment: "_where i = 1, 2, …, k and j = 1, 2, …, n_" -- But array indices start from 0 and end at length-1 in C. Did you mean "where i = 0, 1, 2, …, k-1 and j = 0, 1, 2, …, n-1"?

Comment: "_C[i][j] = A[i][1]*B[1][j]+ A[i][2]*B[2][j]+ ,..., A[i][m]*B[m][j]_" Same mistake. See above comment ↑

Comment: Hint: You need three nested loops. Two of them can be seen in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34481841/3049655) answer. The third one should calculate the value of "A[i][0]*B[0][j]+ A[i][1]*B[1][j]+ ,..., A[i][m-1]*B[m-1][j]" and store it in a variable.  Assign his value to `C[i][j]` just after the inner-most loop.

Comment: okay I'm having a look now, cheers! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Matrix A has size kxm and matrix B has size mxn .Resultant matrix would have the size kxn .
So you can start the for loop as below .

```
for (i=0;i<k;i++)
  for(j=0;i<n;j++)
  {
     //perform the desired operation in matrix C .
  }
```

Please note : you are using "m" twice .its redundant .

Comment: what confusing me is the number of columns in A equal to the number of rows in B which is "m", so I think there might be some conflicts when I scan two matrix seperately...

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this, array of matrix is used instead of using A, B, C. "row" and "col" are for storing the dimensions of matrix, notice `col[0]` should be equal to `row[1]`.

```
float matrix[3][10][10];
int i, j, k, row[2], col[2];
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
  printf("Enter the number of rows and columns of matrix %d:\n", i+1);
  scanf("%d %d", &row[i], &col[i]);
  for(j=0; j<row[i]; j++)
    for(k=0; k<col[i]; k++)
      scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j][k]);
}
```